# Fibonacci error: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Tags: python, recursion

I am on python version 3.4.1 and when I run the code:

```
def fibo(n):
    if n == 1 or n ==2:
        return 1
    else:
        return fibo(n-1)+fibo(n-2)

print("input number for fibonacci seq list")
num = int(input())
for i in range(0,num):
    print(str(fibo(i)))
```

I would want the code to give me a list of the fibonacci numbers that the user input but I get the error mentioned in the title. I am not sure why.

Comment: How big is the number you input ?

Comment: Tried small cases like 3 4 5.  Same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am not sure why.

Let me explain what is going on.

At this part:

```
for i in range(0,num):
    print(str(fibo(i)))
```

the first number `i` passed to `fibo` is `0` because `range(0,num)` starts at `0`.  Inside `fibo`, `0` fails the `n == 1 or n ==2` condition, so `fibo(n-1)` is executed.  Now the number is `-1` because `0 - 1 == -1`.  This number also fails the `n == 1 or n ==2` condition and `fibo(n-1)` is executed again.  Now the number is `-2`.

Hopefully, you see where this is going.  The number is decreased indefinitely until `fibo` reaches Python's maximum recursion depth and thereby raises an error.

Answer (score 0):

You start by trying to calculate fibo(0) which results in infinite recursion - do 'range(1,n)'

Comment: or just set the `if-statement` to `if n <= 2:`

Answer (score 0):

Fibonacci recursion increases geometrically.  It is better to use iteration or a generator.

Here's a generator:

```
>>> def fibgen():
...   a,b=1,1
...   while True:
...     yield a
...     a,b=b,a+b
...
>>> i = fibgen()
>>> next(i)
1
>>> next(i)
1
>>> next(i)
2
>>> next(i)
3
>>> next(i)
5
>>> i=fibgen()
>>> [next(i) for _ in range(10)]
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
```